# tinys3 not recognizing folder on upload (django) (s3)

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

My code:

```
csv = pd.read_html(table)[0].to_csv('datasource_files/testtable7.csv',index=False,header=False)
conn = tinys3.Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,endpoint='s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/')
csv_file=open('datasource_files/testtable7.csv')
csv_file=open('datasource_files/testtable7.csv','rb')
csv_name= 'datasource_files/testtable7.csv'
conn.upload(csv_name,csv_file,'datafix1')
ds = DataSource.objects.create(file=csv_name,datatype="CSV",creator=mike, title="title",description="desc")
```

DataSource is a Django model, file is a models.FileField(). Currently, ds.file is http://datafix1.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/datasource_files/testtable7.csv but that file doesn't exist. In order to access the file uploaded I need to go to http://datafix1.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com//datasource_files/testtable7.csv (which has an empty directory appended at the beginning of the pathname, because tinys3 is not recognizing the already existing (important) "datasource_files" folder (at least I believe that is the reason, I may be wrong). Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used boto3 instead, works like a charm